# Invalid index [0] for array. Index must be a positive integer

Tags: coldfusion, railo

The following code worked in Adobe ColdFusion but since migrating to Railo gives me the following error:

**Error Messages: Invalid index [0] for array. Index must be a positive integer (1, 2, 3, ...)**

Error is on line starting: **local.arrChartDataResult=addPercentageData(local.arrChartDataResult)**

Any idea why this is the case?

```
   <cffunction name="getAverageChartData" hint="I return the data required to render an average chart." returntype="array" output="false">
        <cfargument name="surveyList" hint="I am a record set of Surveys." required="true" type="query" />
        <cfargument name="filter" hint="I am the optional filter which is to be applied to all results." required="false" default="" type="string" />

        <cfset var local=structNew() />

        <cfset var rstChartData="" />
        <cfset var rstChartDataTotal="" />
        <cfset var rstCombinedChartData=queryNew("itemColumn,valueColumn,label","varchar,integer,varchar") />

        <cfset local.objQuestion=objQuestionService.get(arguments.surveyList.question_ID[1]) />
        <cfset local.intQuestionTypeID = local.objQuestion.getTypeID() />

        <cfset local.strSubQuestionList=local.objQuestion.getAnswer() />
        <cfset local.strPossibleAnswerList=local.objQuestion.getPossibleAnswer() />

        <cfset local.arrChartDataResult=arrayNew(1) />

<!--- loop over each school's survey --->
        <cfloop query="arguments.surveyList">
            <cfset local.arrChartData = getChartData(arguments.surveyList.survey_id, arguments.surveyList.question_id, arguments.filter) />

<!--- loop over each sub question and append (union) it to a running total --->
            <cfloop array="#local.arrChartData#" index="rstChartData">
                <cfquery name="rstCombinedChartData" dbtype="query">
                    SELECT
                         itemColumn
                        ,valueColumn
                        ,label
                    FROM
                        rstCombinedChartData

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                         itemColumn
                        ,CAST(valueColumn AS INTEGER) AS valueColumn
                        ,label
                    FROM
                        rstChartData
                </cfquery>
            </cfloop>
        </cfloop>

        <cfif local.intQuestionTypeID EQ 17>
            <cfquery name="rstChartDataTotal" dbtype="query">
                SELECT
                     itemColumn
                    ,AVG(valueColumn) AS valueColumn
                    ,label
                FROM
                    rstCombinedChartData
                GROUP BY
                     label
                    ,itemColumn
                ORDER BY
                     label DESC
                    <!---,itemColumn DESC--->
            </cfquery>
        <cfelse>
<!--- get the totals for each itemColumn --->
            <cfquery name="rstChartDataTotal" dbtype="query">
                SELECT
                     itemColumn
                    ,SUM(valueColumn) AS valueColumn
                    ,label
                FROM
                    rstCombinedChartData
                GROUP BY
                     label
                    ,itemColumn
                ORDER BY
                     label DESC
                    ,itemColumn DESC
            </cfquery>
        </cfif>

<!--- add sort order column to query and populate it with the order in which the sub questions are asked --->
        <cfset rstChartDataTotal=orderByQuestion(rstChartDataTotal, local.strSubQuestionList) />

<!--- if this is a one-dimensional question --->
        <cfif arrayLen(local.arrChartData) EQ 1>
            <cfset local.arrChartDataResult[1]=addPercentageData_Old(rstChartDataTotal) />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset arrayResize(local.arrChartDataResult, listLen(local.strPossibleAnswerList)) />

            <cfoutput query="rstChartDataTotal" group="label">
                <cfset local.intPositionInArray=listFindNoCase(local.strPossibleAnswerList, rstChartDataTotal.label, True) />

                <cfoutput>
                    <cfquery name="local.rstChartData" dbtype="query">
                        SELECT
                             itemColumn
                            ,valueColumn
                            ,label
                            ,sortOrder
                        FROM
                            rstChartDataTotal
                        WHERE
                            label = '#rstChartDataTotal.label#'
                        ORDER BY
                            sortOrder
                    </cfquery>
                </cfoutput>


                <cfset local.arrChartDataResult[local.intPositionInArray]=local.rstChartData>
            </cfoutput>

            <cfset local.arrChartDataResult=addPercentageData(local.arrChartDataResult) />
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn local.arrChartDataResult />
    </cffunction>
```

Full Error:

```
Application Execution Exception
Error Type: expression : 0
Error Messages: Invalid index [0] for array. Index must be a positive integer (1, 2, 3, ...)


Template:   /srv/www/testapp/admin/model/response/ResponseService.cfc



Current Event:  pdf.createPDF
Current Layout:     N/A
Current View:   N/A
Bug Date:   07/29/2013 10:53:19 AM
Coldfusion ID:  CFID=c07b7b4e-d79e-4688-950d-20f0192a27ca ; CFToken=0 ; JSessionID=4A3B1BC689B4C438DAAF1088A42A6481_c07b7b4e-d79e-4688-950d-20f0192a27ca_0
Template Path :     /srv/www/testapp/admin/index.cfm
Path Info :     /pdf/createPDF
Host & Server:  management.testapp.co.uk:8888 ip-172-31-24-53
Query String:   
Referrer:   http://management.testapp.co.uk:8888/index.cfm/home?fwreinit=1
Browser:    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0



Invalid index [0] for array. Index must be a positive integer (1, 2, 3, ...)
    at railo.runtime.type.ArrayImpl.setE(ArrayImpl.java:226):226
    at railo.runtime.type.ArrayImpl.set(ArrayImpl.java:205):205
    at railo.runtime.type.util.ArraySupport.set(ArraySupport.java:360):360
    at railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.set(VariableUtilImpl.java:437):437
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.set(PageContextImpl.java:1266):1266
    at model.response.responseservice_cfc$cf._1(/srv/www/testapp/admin/model/response/ResponseService.cfc:268):268
    at model.response.responseservice_cfc$cf.udfCall(/srv/www/testapp/admin/model/response/ResponseService.cfc):-1
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:607):607
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1781):1781
    at railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:723):723
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1506):1506
    at handlers.pdf_cfc$cf.udfCall(/srv/www/testapp/admin/handlers/pdf.cfc:289):289
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:275):275
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:608):608
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1796):1796
    at railo.runtime.tag.Invoke.doComponent(Invoke.java:209):209
    at railo.runtime.tag.Invoke.doEndTag(Invoke.java:182):182
    at system.web.controller_cfc$cf._6(/srv/www/testapp/admin/framework/coldbox_standalone_3.0.0.RC1/system/web/Controller.cfc:662):662
    at system.web.controller_cfc$cf.udfCall(/srv/www/testapp/admin/framework/coldbox_standalone_3.0.0.RC1/system/web/Controller.cfc):-1
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284
    at railo.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.call(UndefinedImpl.java:775):775
    at railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:723):723
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1506):1506
    at system.web.controller_cfc$cf._5(/srv/www/testapp/admin/framework/coldbox_standalone_3.0.0.RC1/system/web/Controller.cfc:553):553
    at system.web.controller_cfc$cf.udfCall(/srv/www/testapp/admin/framework/coldbox_standalone_3.0.0.RC1/system/web/Controller.cfc):-1
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:275):275
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:608):608
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1800):1800
    at railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:749):749
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1521):1521
    at system.coldbox_cfc$cf._1(/srv/www/testapp/admin/framework/coldbox_standalone_3.0.0.RC1/system/Coldbox.cfc:226):226
    at system.coldbox_cfc$cf.udfCall(/srv/www/testapp/admin/framework/coldbox_standalone_3.0.0.RC1/system/Coldbox.cfc):-1
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:607):607
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1781):1781
    at railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:723):723
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1506):1506
    at application_cfc$cf.udfCall(/srv/www/rudifferent/admin/Application.cfc:54):54
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:103):103
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:371):371
    at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:284):284
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:607):607
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:490):490
    at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1781):1781
    at railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener.call(ModernAppListener.java:346):346
    at railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:107):107
    at railo.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:18):18
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2255):2255
    at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2222):2222
    at railo.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:315):315
    at railo.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:29):29
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728):728
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305):305
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210):210
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222):222
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123):123
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472):472
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171):171
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99):99
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118):118
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407):407
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004):1004
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589):589
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312):312
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source):-1
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source):-1
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source):-1
```

Comment: Hi @Adam Cameron thanks for the response. It does state that the error is on the line stated tho in my railo error. However, I'll update my OP with full error now :)

Comment: @Adam Cameron I have also added the full function to the OP above if that will help. many thanks

Comment: I'm running Railo 4.0.4.001 final on port :8888 on Ubuntu Server 12

Comment: It looks to me like `intPositionInArray` is getting set to zero because the `listFindNoCase()` ain't finding anything. Have you checked that?

Comment: error output is gray just like Adobe CF, but 100% it's Railo 4.0.4.001 fresh install running on Ubuntu I don't have Adobe CF installed at all. I copied all files over from an Adobe 10 machine tho, but that makes no difference I don't think.

Comment: @Adam Cameron the same code works on Adobe CF does listFindNoCase work different in Railo? i.e in Adobe CF does null or blank = 0?

Comment: Don't worry about what works on another system. Focus on why it doesn't work on *this* system. Did you check the value I mentioned? And, no, the behaviour of the `listFindNoCase()` function is the same on Railo as CF in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you've posted the relevant code, based on where you say the error is occurring, but my strong suspicion is that the code in `addPercentageData()` is leveraging - by design or otherwise - the fact that ColdFusion passes arrays by value. However Railo passes 'em by reference, so you are possibly interfering with data in your calling code, when you were assuming you were simply working on a copy of the data local to your function.

This is just an educated guess though.